Zeppelin 0.11.1 with Spark 3.3 - Spark Interpreter Fails with NoSuchFileException
Receiving an InterpreterException when submitting spark job through Zeppelin:
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /zzz/ppp/lll/Zeppelin/zeppelin-0.11.1-bin-all/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar

The file is in the location. I changed ownership and gave it read write access but still ended up with the same outcome.
I checked with the Spark Master and in the worker it states ava.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /zzz/ppp/lll/Zeppelin/zeppelin-0.11.1-bin-all/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar
so the request is making to the Workers on the Spark cluster but then errors out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is recommended to execute in the following order.

Install and extract Spark binary files locally

# Install
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.2/spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3.tgz

# Extract
tar -xvf spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3.tgz


Create a Docker Compose file (docker-compose-with-spark.yml)

services:
  zeppelin:
    hostname: zeppelin
    container_name: zeppelin
    image: docker.io/apache/zeppelin:0.11.2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      ZEPPELIN_PORT: 8080
      ZEPPELIN_MEM: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
      SPARK_HOME: /opt/spark
    volumes:
      - ./spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3:/opt/spark

  spark-master:
    hostname: spark-master
    container_name: spark-master
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.2
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: master
      SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_SSL_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_USER: spark
      SPARK_MASTER_PORT: 7077
      SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT: 8080

  spark-worker:
    hostname: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.2
    ports:
      - "18081:8081"
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2G
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_SSL_ENABLED: no
      SPARK_USER: spark
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
    depends_on:
      - spark-master


Run Docker Compose

docker compose -f docker-compose-with-spark.yml up


Create and run a Zeppelin notebook

%spark.conf

SPARK_HOME /opt/spark
spark.master spark://spark-master:7077

%spark

val sdf = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((0, "park", 13, 70, "Korea"), (1, "xing", 14, 80, "China"), (2, "john", 15, 90, "USA"))).toDF("id", "name", "age", "score", "country")
sdf.printSchema
sdf.show()

Result
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- score: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
+---+----+---+-----+-------+
| id|name|age|score|country|
+---+----+---+-----+-------+
|  0|park| 13|   70|  Korea|
|  1|xing| 14|   80|  China|
|  2|john| 15|   90|    USA|
+---+----+---+-----+-------+

